# How to apply toggling / styles on a particular clicked card only in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I developed one page DisplayBooks.vue which is responsible for displaying books the response is coming from backend API based on that data it will displayed in my UI page , in my UI page each card contains Two buttons(ADD TO BAG & ADDED TO BAG) when ever user click on any  card ADD TO BAG button at that time it will hide ADDTOBAG and displays ADDED TO BAG button on a particular clicked card only , please help me to acheive this thing.

`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card book">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img  v-bind:src="book.file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-section">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by {{book.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
            <button v-if="flag" class="btn-grp" type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button-groups">
                <button type="button"  class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
                
            </div>
            <div  class="AddedBag">
                <button class="big-btn">Added to Bag</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
           
            flag: true,
            state: true,
            clickedCard: '',
            books: [{
                id: 0,
                file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                name: 'Dont Make me think',
                author: 'Sai',
                price: '1500'
            }, ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
       
        
        flip() {
            this.state = !this.state;
        },
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {
                this.books.push(...response.data);     
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "@/styles/DisplayBooks.scss";
</style>
```

`DisplayBooks.scss`

```
@import "colors";
.carddisplay-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.card:hover{
    box-shadow:0.6px 0.6px 0.6px 0.6px rgb(173, 206, 206);
}
.card {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    background:$pink;
    // width: 235px;
    // height: 275px;
    width: 235px;
height: 315px;
    background: $pale_white 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid $border_clr;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-section {
    width: 233px;
    height: 172px;
    background: #F5F5F5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

img{
    margin-left: 67px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    width: 105px;
    height: 135px;
    opacity: 1;
    border:none;
}

.title-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/19px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 19px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.author-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 123px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.price-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 12px/16px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;

}

label {
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
    font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 36px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 65px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 15;
}
.button-groups{
    display:flex;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.AddBag{
    background: #A03037 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 93px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
}
.wishlist{
    margin-left:4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
    border: 1px solid #7c7a7a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #0A0102;
    width:93px;
}
.big-btn{
    width: 191px;
height: 29px;
margin-left:20px;
background: #3371B5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 2px;
opacity: 1;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another array which will contain the books ids added by clicking on the button **ADD To BAG** then use `v-if/v-else` to make a conditional rendering :

```
    data() {
        return {
           
            flag: true,
            state: true,
            clickedCard: '',
            addedBooks:[],
            books: [....]
        }
    },
```

in the template :

```
    <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button-groups" v-if="!addedBooks.includes(book.id)">
                <button type="button"  @click="addedBooks.push(book.id)"  class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
                
            </div>
            <div  class="AddedBag" v-else>
                <button class="big-btn" @click="addedBooks=addedBooks.filter(id=>id!==book.id)">Added to Bag</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Example**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {

      flag: true,
      state: true,
      clickedCard: '',
      addedBooks: [],
      books: [{
          id: 0,
          file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
          name: 'Dont Make me think',
          author: 'Sai',
          price: '1500'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          file: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41MdP5Tn0wL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
          name: 'Dont Make me think',
          author: 'Sai',
          price: '1500'
        },

      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {


    flip() {
      this.state = !this.state;
    },
    Togglebtn() {
      this.flag = !this.flag;
    },

  }
})
```

```css
.carddisplay-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0.6px 0.6px 0.6px 0.6px rgb(173, 206, 206);
}

.card {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 110px;
  background: $pink;
  // width: 235px;
  // height: 275px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 315px;
  background: $pale_white 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid $border_clr;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-section {
  width: 233px;
  height: 172px;
  background: #F5F5F5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

img {
  margin-left: 67px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 135px;
  opacity: 1;
  border: none;
}

.title-section {
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/19px Roboto;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  color: $light_black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 19px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.author-section {
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 13px/13px Roboto;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: $light_grey;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 123px;
  height: 13px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.price-section {
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal bold 12px/16px Roboto;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: $light_black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

label {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
  font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: $light_grey;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 36px;
  height: 13px;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  padding-left: 65px;
  background: none;
  font-size: 15;
}

.button-groups {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.AddBag {
  background: #A03037 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 93px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: small;
}

.wishlist {
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: small;
  border: 1px solid #7c7a7a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #0A0102;
  width: 93px;
}

.big-btn {
  width: 191px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #3371B5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card book">
      <div class="image-section">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img v-bind:src="book.file" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title-section">
        {{book.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="author-section">
        by {{book.author}}
      </div>
      <div class="price-section">
        Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
        <button v-if="flag" class="btn-grp" type="submit" @click="">close</button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="button-groups" v-if="!addedBooks.includes(book.id)">
          <button type="button" @click="addedBooks.push(book.id)" class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>

        </div>
        <div class="AddedBag" v-else>
          <button class="big-btn" @click="addedBooks=addedBooks.filter(id=>id!==book.id)">Added to Bag</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: onclick of ADDED TO BAG button it should hides and displays the ADD TO BAG functionality is not working

Comment: please clarify more

Comment: when user clicks on ADD TO BAG button at that time it hides the ADD TO BAG button and displays the ADDED TO BAG button upto this it's working  ,like this only when user again clicks on ADDED TO BAG button it should return to the ADD TO BAG button (means ADDED TO BAG  button should be hidden)

Comment: is `addedBooks`  filling with added ids?

Comment: yeah  it's filling ,@Boussadjra Brahim

Comment: Try `v-if="!addedBooks.find(id=>id!==book.id)"` instead of `v-if="!addedBooks.includes(book.id)"`

Comment: it's not working and previous toggling functionality also not working when i use new v-if condition

Comment: the first solution should work as mentioned in the new example, please check my edited answer

Comment: in your snippet also when i click on ADDED TO BAG button it's not hidden, My requirement is when i click on ADDED TO BAG button it should be hide and displays the ADD TO BAG button

Comment: Try out `<button class="big-btn" @click="addedBooks=addedBooks.filter(id=>id!==book.id)">Added to Bag</button>`